# JavaScript date picker in HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have built a Prediction table which will contain football data. Please I need a JavaScript date picker code that will fit into this table I built.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: px;
}

th {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

th,
td {
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  background-color
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><b>England » Premier</b></th>
    <th><b>Prediction</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> &nbsp;24-06:20:16</td>
    <td>Red Bull Bragantino <b style="color:red"> &nbsp;2 : 1 &nbsp;</b> Ponte Preta</td>
    <td style="background-color:none;color:none;"><b>Home Win</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I will be grateful if someone could help me out.

Comment: You wanted a datapicker to be available in the HTML table ?

Comment: Yes I need a date picker in the HTML table

Comment: There is alot of example available on the web. Please try to look for solutions as your asking the community to code for you instead of trying out yourself. Here is an example regarding your question. [DatePicker Example](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: I have tried to code it but all attempt failed, that was why I brought it here if someone could help me out. If you can I will be grateful.

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: Each time I tried call out a date from the table, it doesn't respond. It just pick the date but doesn't call out the data from the table.

Comment: The answer i just gave is only to enable the datepicker function. If you want to get the value from the datepicker, just simply use form with POST method to enable PHP to process your data into database or anywhere you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks slot man. I am grateful

Answer (score -1):

I advice to actually try and look for solutions.

Below is the solution to your question where the website i gave actually thought you step by step to create a datepicker.

First of all you will need jquery to be able to use datepicker. There is few ways for you to get jquery datepicker CSS & JS file. For me, i prefer using CDN as it is much conveniet. Usually JS scripts are recommended to be placed before the body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th><b>Datepicker</b></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="datepicker"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot I am very grateful.

Comment: @SteveKush, he/she can upvote with 11 rep?